# Can't convert a string to an integer from a list

Tags: integer

I have a file with names and scores, example would be tom,50..I want to print the highest score and name but keep getting 'invalid literal for int() with base 10: '60%''
with open('results.txt','r') as results_file:

```
for line in results_file:
    #split line at , into questions and answers
    if ',' in line:
        name,score=line.strip().split(',')
        score=(int(score))

        leader.append(name)
        topscore.append(score)
  print (max(int(topscore)))
```

please help

Comment: Sounds like your 'topscore' has a '%' sign in it, which can't be parsed by the int() function

Comment: yea it does have a percent sign, is that the problem?

Comment: You should add a tag for the language

Comment: Yeah you will have to remove the '%' character from it before it can be parsed. Try something like '[:-1]' to remove the last character. Bear in mind this will break other scores if not all of them have the '%' at the end

Answer (score 0):

This is because int only accepts an integer without anything else and so won't work with the percent sign. Remove the percent sign using `score[:-1]` (return score without the last character).